# What is the difference between a DICOM viewer vs a PACS system or RIS

Tags: imaging, medical, medical-imaging

I have installed OsiriX is my computer which is an open source DICOM viewer. I was wondering what would make this different from a PACS (Picture archiving and communication system) or RIS (Radiology Information System). How could OsiriX be incorporated into one of them?

Just trying to get a better understanding of this 3 apparently different but interrelated concepts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The viewer is an application that allows you to look at images.  The PACS is a server that stores the images (they often have an accompanying viewer).  The RIS is a workflow/record system for scheduling the time for the scanners, managing appointments, storing reports, etc.

Comment: Thank you! I am trying to develop an application that has some interaction (sends and receives information) with these systems. From what you mention it seems like I will need to setup both PACS & RIS. Are there any open-source setups? Can I used OsiriX as the viewer for an Open-Source PACS, or is this integration better done by the vendor/distributor? Should I just focus on finding an open-source PACS software with a good DICOM viewer?

Comment: @Prussian I don't directly use RIS systems, so I can't comment there.  We do however often use dcm4chee as an open source PACS system.  I has an associated web viewer.  There are a few libraries (open source and commercial, some better than others) that you can use if you need to develop an application that interacts with a PACS (in no particular order: RZDCM, Lead Tools, Clear Canvas, GDCM, mdcm, fellow oak dicom, dcmtk, DVTK, MyDICOM).

Answer (score 0):

OsiriX  have both options means -  Storage and viewer basically called Osirix was PACS but **stand alone**.  Every PACS has its own viewer now a days either server client basis or web viewer. Dicom work station was different and PACS viewer was different.

RIS was Radiology information System which contains Process of Radiology dept. `Scan orders > scheduling > Generating Modality work list >  scan reports > Modality reports > MIS reports > Billing (Optional) > Radiology reporting > Reports dispatch > Sending reports to PACS etc.`
 IT will communicate with `PACS` through  `HL7`.  `PACS` and `RIS` should be two different servers but some are available both in same then it wont suitable for bigger workflows.